# How to ignore accept-charset header in .Net Core API

Tags: api, .net-core, encoding

I have a .NET Core 5.0 API, in that one endpoint will produce the XML, here produce attribute is added to the endpoint like
`[Produces("application/xml","text/xml")]`

Client calling this API sending a header **accept-charset** with both **utf-16** and **utf-8**.
this results in junk chars in the response.
[image]

[image]

[image]

(Here somehow if I identify utf-16 in content-type and pass utf-16 encoding to StreamReader will fix the problem at this place, but at client also same chars are coming)

Is there a way in .NET Core to Ignore **accept-charset** header for an endpoint and force to utf-8?

I tried configuring it in the MvcOptions like below but not working

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options=> {
                var settings=options.OutputFormatters
                             .OfType<XmlSerializerOutputFormatter>()
                             .Single()
                             .WriterSettings;

                settings.Encoding=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
            });
```

Comment: The problem is in the client code, or at least this code that uses StreamReader. The response is UTF16 but `StreamReader` uses the default encoding, UTF8. Use a constructor that accepts an `Encoding` parameter and pass `Encoding.UTF16` as the encoding. Clients should handle this automatically. Eg `HttpClient` always uses the response's `charset` to decode the content

Comment: Do you have actual client code that has trouble with this response?

Comment: In API side to StreamReader constructor if I pass UTF-16 will work, but the client sending this accept-charset header with UTF-16 and UTF-8 and I guess it is not actually handling the UTF-16, unfortunately I don't have any control over the client
I am able to replicate this by passing the header in PostMan

Comment: You didn't replicate any bug. The *client* asked for UTF16 and actually placed it first in the list. You returned what the client specifically asked for, you're OK. If the client can't handle what they *explicitly* asked, you can't do anything. What makes you thing that `utf-8` isn't wrong too?

Comment: `I don't have any control over the client` what client is this anyway? In what language is it written? Why do you assume there's any problem to solve? What made you post this question?

Comment: This client is an external tool (NCPDP pharmacy testing tool) where they won't change how they call the webhook, I confirmed through support that if we send utf-8 then it won't show junk chars in that tool
I am looking is there a way to force charset encoding when the accept-charset header is there

Comment: That's not what I asked. I'll have to repeat the same comments. *They* explicitly asked for UTF16. There are no junk characters in that response. In UTF16 all characters are encoded using 2 or more bytes, even if that byte is `0x00`. US-ASCII letters are encoded using `0x00` as the first byte and the actual ASCII byte as the second. The got what they asked. If they don't like UTF16 they shouldn't ask for it

Comment: What makes you think that the client will be able to handle non-ASCII text if you ignore what they asked and use UTF8? Even English words use accents, eg `naïve` or `Charlotte Brontë`. In both UTF16 and UTF8 these characters will be encoded using multiple bytes.

Comment: Yes, I agree, API sent a response for whatever the client asked for but in reality, the client was not able to handle this UTF-16, so I am trying to force encoding or to ignore the accept-charset header

Comment: No, in reality *they* are forced to stop requesting UTF16. That's their bug. What makes you assume they can handle UTF8?

Comment: And once again, why do you assume there's a problem? Who reported it? What is the *actual* problem they reported? Until now you haven't described *any problem at all*. You *haven't* shown any junk characters

Comment: I am unable to show the client's tool screen, but there instead of showing the XML response, it shows some chars, however, it will show the correct XML when UTF-8.
my question / problem is is there a way to discard particular request headers or enforce encoding in response?

Comment: No, you only know that the tool works with US-ASCII. UTF8 and US-ASCII use the same bytes for the first 128 characters. You have no idea what would happen with characters outside that range, including symbols, fractions, Greek letters, accented characters. That's very bad when it comes to prescriptions. You'd end up with mangled or lost text. UTF8 would send *two* or more bytes for every character above 128. You realize that if you modify your service to match a broken testing tool, it won't work when used by the *real* service?